# Evaluate a binary classifier in the presence of unbalanced and unlabeled data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, training-data

## Setup

My data is made of **N** elements that I want to label **0** or **1**. Those two classes are *unbalanced* by nature: I know that from those **N** elements, there are much more negative examples than positive ones.

From a precision-oriented heuristics, I can get a small subsample of positive examples with a high precision **b ~ 0.9**. The size of this positive set is **g.N**, where **g << 1**. I call this the positive set.

The elements that are not in the positive set are in their vast majority negative. Let's call it the negative set.

However, a small fraction **a ~ 0.03** of them is indeed positive. In absolute numbers though, the number of positive elements in the negative set is much higher than the number of positive elements in the positive set: **a.(1-g).N >> b.g.N**

## Evaluation Problem

Assuming we have a classifier, we can compute precision, recall and F-measure based on the positive and negative sets defined above. Though it does not seem to be very meaningful. Here is why.

An ideal classifier that never fails would get a recall of **b** and a precision of **bg / (bg + a(1-g)) << 1**.

A classifier that just remembers what is in the positive set and the negative set would have a precision, a recall and a F-measure of 1.

The F-measure seems to indicate that the memory classifier is much better. However, the ideal classifier is the one that really solves the problem: correctly label *all* the positive and *all* the negative examples.

## Question

Fixing the values of **a**, **b**, and **g**, what is a correct way to *evaluate* a binary classifier in presence of unbalanced and unlabeled data ? Note that I am not trying to train a classifier, but only evaluate an existing one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: moving to datascience then! Thanks !

Comment: @Oliver: You should not open a new question. This is a moderator action. They will move your question, if they think it is appropriate. It will not be "closed" in the usual sense. Don't worry, you don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using AUC of the ROC curve, which is robust to the class imbalance issue you describe.  The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) provides a good description if you are unfamiliar.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to come up with a reasonable cost function. How much does it cost to confuse class A with B? How much vice versa? How much does it cost to get class A / B correct? Then you can calculate the cost on a given test set.

> A classifier that just remembers what is in the positive set and the negative set would have a precision, a recall and a F-measure of 1.

You have to make a separate training and test set. The test set is never seen during training by the classifier. Otherwise, you cannot get a meaningful evaluation. Or you don't have a machine learning problem.

> The F-measure seems to indicate that the memory classifier is much better. However, the ideal classifier is the one that really solves the problem: correctly label all the positive and all the negative examples.

If your problem is complicated enough, you will never get a perfect classifier. However, without having more information about your problem I can't say more about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Martin! You are right about the training set and test set and I am doing it. I know I will never get a perfect classifier and those two examples are purely hypothetical, but the comment is still valid I suppose. Even if I did have one, I would not be able to know I do.